# How to prevent eshell interpret bash shell command?

Tags: eshell

I want to execute the `source` shell command from the *eshell* environment in Emacs. But the `source` is also a lisp function, so the two command confilicts, and eshell always execute the `source` function, instead of the `source` shell command.

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this [blog](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/complete-guide-mastering-eshell). Quote:

> All commands evaluated by Eshell have an evaluation order, which is an ordered list your command must pass through to determine what part of Eshell handles it. If there is nothing on the list that wants to evaluate your command, you will be told your command is invalid.

So the problem is that the lisp `source` function comes before the `source` command. To fix this, we need to tell `eshell` explicitly that we want to execute a shell command. And the answer is in this variable:

> eshell-explicit-command-char (default is *)

Comment: Please explain this answer more so that future readers will be able to follow it.